# could not resolve plugin artifact o.fabric:io.fabric.gradle.plugin Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, build.gradle, crashlytics-android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am getting the following error when trying to build the project.
The only difference is the gradle script is in Kotlin DSL.

```
could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.fabric:io.fabric.gradle.plugin:1.25.4')
```

Below is my entire build.gradle.kts file

https://gist.github.com/nksaroj/483f3f07df8e04c72040ea4c055459d6

Or https://github.com/nksaroj/xDemo is the full project.

Comment: I have the same issue.
Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Some work around. Just move the class path to the root level build.gradle. this is not solution because this works locally but fails in the CI server. Let me know if you found any better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use applying plugin in build block:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:applying_plugins_buildscript

For io.fabric:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven("https://maven.fabric.io/public")
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4")
    }
}
```